# Sync android database over multiple devices through Google or Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-fql, google-account

i'm going to develop a sort of cloud based application. Since I develop for hobby, I don't want to pay a server. 
I'm wondering if Google or Facebook allow user to sync sqlite OR json databases through their server. For example: I'd like to sync - after the Google+ app login - the data of my app, so that the same person, on his tablet, can use the data he produced on the smartphone. Can anyone point me out some documentation that explain me what services should I use and how? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With every Google account comes [Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/). That link leads to the documentation for their API, but you will want to use their [libraries](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-java) as I presume.

Basic understanding of OAuth workflow can be beneficial.